# VS2015 Error while trying to add Push Notification to my Windows 8.1 Universal App project C#

Tags: push-notification, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps

I am using Visual Studio 2015, blank Universal windows 8.1 App template.
Language use C#.
When I run (any project) everything is working just fine, except for one thing, I cannot open the Push Notification Wizard.
When I do the following:
right click on myProject --> Add --> Push Notification... I got the following error:
[Error Vs Push Notification Wizard Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePZXT.png)

Anybody has an idea what's happening?
Thank you for your time.